# Simple if window is greater than not working

Tags: jquery, resize

I'm struggling with this simple if structure in a responsive design. Basically it's a nav element switches from dropdown to a float list. When resizing within 960px, the dropdown is not working. Is there something wrong with my current code?

```
$(window).load(function(){
var windowWidth = $(window).width();
function checkSize() {
    if(windowWidth < 960) {
        quickDrop();
    }
}
function quickDrop(){
    $("#quicklinks").hover(function() {
        $("#quicklinks > ul").stop(true,true).slideDown("fast");
        $sitesArrow.css({ WebkitTransform: 'rotate(270deg)'});
        $sitesArrow.css({ '-moz-transform': 'rotate(270deg)'});
    }, function(){
        $("#quicklinks > ul").stop(true,true).slideUp("fast");
        $sitesArrow.css({ WebkitTransform: 'rotate(0deg)'});
        $sitesArrow.css({ '-moz-transform': 'rotate(0deg)'});
    });
}
checkSize();

$(window).resize(function(){
    checkSize();
});
});
```

Thank you!

http://jsfiddle.net/bdGPz/

Comment: Could you put it up on a fiddle ?

Comment: Change `if(windowWidth < 960)` to `if($(window).width() < 960)` - you're setting the `windowWidth` variable at run time so it will _not_ get updated every time you call `checkSize()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put `var windowWidth = $(window).width();` within your `checkSize()` function.

```
function checkSize() {
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    if(windowWidth < 960) {
        quickDrop();
    }
}
```

Otherwise `windowWidth` only gets a value on `window.load` and not everytime you request the function `checkSize()`.

Comment: This is the correct answer - I literally just posted this as a comment to the question.

Comment: Yes, this is indeed a step in the good direction. Problem now, is that when i 'activate' the dropdown in /smaller than 960/ and resize back beyond 960px, my #quicklinks ul is gone.

Comment: That only happens when the smaller menu (if window width < 500) is hovered. Because you are hiding the `ul` in `#quicklinks` (via `slideUp('fast')`). Your big menu is also in an `ul` so that gets hidden too.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you doing this with jQuery? You can achieve responsive design much easier by using media queries in CSS, and the browser won't lag every time someone resizes the window.

Comment: Not yet, i'll look into it in the next half hour, thanks already for the suggestions!

Comment: I didn't actually, how would i fix that issue with the missing ul in the 'big' menu?